# Никак не могу понять, в чём моя ошибка

Tags: c++, исключения

В чём моя ошибка? Тут все хорошо:

```
std::string rotation(std::string common,int n)
{
    std::string addition=common.substr(common.size()-n%common.size(), common.size());
    common.erase(common.size()-n%common.size(), common.size());
    common=addition+common;

    return common;
}

std::string encode(int n, std::string str)
{

  std::string str_c=str;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {

    str_c.clear();
   //str_c=rotation(str_c,8); //Here is all ok
    str_c.clear();
  }
  return str_c;

}

 int main() {
   encode(8,"Hello World");
 }
```

А здесь не очень:

```
std::string rotation(std::string common,int n)
    {
        std::string addition=common.substr(common.size()-n%common.size(), common.size());
        common.erase(common.size()-n%common.size(), common.size());
        common=addition+common;
    
        return common;
    }
    
    std::string encode(int n, std::string str)
    {
    
      std::string str_c=str;
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
    
        str_c="some string"
       str_c=rotation(str_c,8); //reason of error
        str_c="some string";
      }
      return str_c;
    
    }
    
     int main() {
       encode(8,"Hello World");
     }
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Исключение в операции с плавающей точкой (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Comment: Отформатируйте код и ошибку, приведите индексируемый заголовок

Comment: по какой логике очищаете строку _  str_c.clear(); ? Чего вы хотите добиваться _ непонятно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим, что же именно передается в функцию rotation. А там пустая строка и число 8.

Теперь открываем первую строку функции rotation и немного ее переформатируем и покоментим

```
std::string addition
  =common.substr(
     common.size()-n%common.size(), // а это 0-8%0. делим на ноль???
     common.size()); // это ноль
```

это паттерн повторяется и в следующей строке.

Comment: Дело не в этом, вопрос поправлен.

Comment: я собрал пример с вопроса 4 разными компиляторами в двух разных ОС. Во всех он спокойно отрабатывает (правда ничего не выводит, но это ожидаемо). Я туда тестового ввода добавил - все работает.